# Title of navigation bar isn't centred after deleting back button title

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

When I deleted the title text of my back button, the text of my navigation title is not centred.

I used

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

and

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -60) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

in both my viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear

[this is a screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GThL6.jpg)

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you still have the same problem if you remove the second line of code in your question?

Comment: Yes, I don't know why, but then it still shows the title of the previous view controller.

Comment: The navbar shows the backBarButtonItem of the previous view controller, that's how it's designed.  You should change this property on the previous view controller.

Comment: This worked, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UINavigationBar` displays the `backBarButtonItem` of the previous view controller, so you'll need to make sure you are setting that and not the `backBarButtonItem` of the displayed view controller.  The call to `setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(_:forBarMetrics:)` is not necessary.